# google-app-engine fails to run Cron job and gives an ImportError: No module named gcloud

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

app-engine fails to import gcloud
used gcloud app deploy app.yaml \cron.yaml to deploy on google app engine

opened on browser and get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~gcp-project-01/20160916t160552.395688991947248655/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    import update_datastore as ud
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~vehicle-monitors-api/20160916t160552.395688991947248655/update_datastore.py", line 20, in <module>
    from gcloud import datastore, logging
ImportError: No module named gcloud
```

The app.yaml file:

```
    runtime: python27
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: true

handlers: 
- url: /
  script: main
  login: admin
```

The cron.yaml file:

```
 cron:
    - description: run main app
      url: /
      target: main
      schedule: every 2 minutes
```

the requirements.txt file:

```
   gcloud==0.14.0
```

Comment: Did you ever install via the requirements file?  e.g. `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt` ?

Comment: @GAEfan I get the same error even after installing the requirements file using pip command as mention by you earlier.

Comment: Too many possibilities.  What does your file tree look like? Is gcloud in your sys.path? Remove `target:main` from cron, as that is not correct.

Comment: `gcloud` needs to be vendored in into your app: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library

Comment: Also in your `app.yaml` your should theoretically have `script: main.app` instead of `script: main` (from the traceback it seems GAE figured it out even without that, but personally I wouldn't rely on it).

Comment: **Trace back after adding appengine_config.py to vendor lib that contains gcloud** \ '  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/my-cron:20161026t102827.396611273014256461/appengine_config.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.appengint.ext import vendor
ImportError: No module named appengint.ext'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working!
Use path:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'lib')
```

**Additional:**
Also need to add protobuf in requirements:
`protobuf==3.1.0.post1`

create `__init__.py` in google folder:

```
# this is a namespace package
try:
    import pkg_resources
    pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    import pkgutil
    __path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

also use `pip install -t lib --upgrade protobuf`

`gcloud==0.18.1` used.

Sorry for the late post

Answer (score 1):

All 3rd party packages need to be installed in the same directory as your app.  Run this from the root directory of your application to install it.

```
pip install gcloud -t .
```

Comment: While this *might* work it is not actually aligned with the recommended 3rd party installation procedure: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library